# R how to not display the number into brackets of the row count in output

Tags: r

I'm trying to get some (dynamic) R output in a website. For instance, a simple count of some values in a dataframe.

```
> data(infert)
> length(infert$age)
[1] 248
```

This "[1]" greatly interferes with the reading :

> We do have currently [1] 248 entries in our database

Is it somehow possible to remove this "[1]" line count in front of the shown result, especially when the output is a unique value?

Comment: What is is that you are trying to do? The `[1]` will only appear in the console output. `cat` and `writeLines` are probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Get `cat`s involved. Felines are not only cute, but good at suppressing line counts.

Comment: Thanks! This works nicely. So I can now embed the R request in a website simple R requests and keep them updated whenever the database has new entries. For info about the tool used: [link](http://tiki.org/forum24)

Comment: I doubt you want this but: `message` as in `message(3)` will remove the bracketed number too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Ananda's comment below!

```
cat(length(infert$age))
```

Does perfectly the trick !